# How many files can I sync from my computer to OneDrive and what's the maximum file size

Tags: onedrive-for-business

Some of my users are having file syncing issues and i'm tying to figure out what the issue could be.
They do work with large files though
The question is how many files can we sync from my computer to OneDrive and what's maximum file size.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Restrictions and limitations in OneDrive and SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#:%7E:text=Number%20of%20items%20that%20can%20be%20synced%20or%20copied&text=When%20using%20onedrive.com%2C%20you,2500%20files%20at%20one%20time.&text=Although%20SharePoint%20can%20store%2030,files%20across%20all%20document%20libraries.)**

> Although SharePoint can store 30 million documents per library, for optimum performance we recommend syncing no more than 300,000 files across all document libraries. Performance issues can occur if you have 300,000 items or more across all libraries that you are syncing, even if you are not syncing all items within those libraries.

> If OneDrive sync seems to be stuck for a long time or the status shows "Processing 0KB of xMB" it could be because you have a lot of files in your OneDrive or a lot of new files to be uploaded. If you have more than 100,000 files, sync can take a long time.

I was personally able to sync over a million files and it still worked fine. I did it only as a test.

Comment: Thanks Denis for the info

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, there is currently no documentation stating OneDrive sync file limit. But there are still the following restrictions:

- If you have more than **100,000 files**, sync can take a long time.
- Maximum file upload size updated to **250 GB**. This applies to an individual file being uploaded or synced, not your total storage. For
  any file larger than **a few GB**, we recommend using the OneDrive
  sync app rather than the website upload feature.

For more information, please see the "**[Restrictions and limitations in OneDrive and SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#synctoomany)**" article.

Comment: Thanks EchoDu for the info

Comment: Hi naijacoder. I'm glad I can help you. Have a nice day!